# How to remove vertical Minimap in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

How do I remove the **minimap** that appears in the side as vertical scrollbar in **Visual Studio**? It's causing me visual issues and is occupying extra space in display screen.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Step 1:
**Right click on minimap** displayed on your visual studio screen on the vertical scroll bar.

Step:2: **Click scroll bar option**, then the screen below appears.
[image]

Step 3:
Switch from **use map mode for vertical scroll bar** to **use bar mode** as displayed above in the screen.

Step 4: Click **OK**.

Comment: Interesting; mine did not have a "check" in either radio button, why it was not intuitive for me to switch it off.

Answer (score 13):

**Solution 1.**

Go to menu `TOOLS` \ `Options...`

Choose `Text Editor` \ `All Languages` \ `Scroll Bars`.

Section `Behavior`, choose `Use bar mode for vertical scroll bar`, then press <kbd>OK</kbd>.

[image]

**Solution 2**: Right-click at vertical scroll bar, then change settings.

[image]