# How can I turn on the minimap slider in VS 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I want to display the minimap slider on the right side of VS 2019 Community, but I didn't find any option for this.. Google said that I need to use Visual Studio Code because only this version include the minimap option. I saw in this [tutorial video](https://youtu.be/1OsGXuNA5cc?list=PLlrATfBNZ98dudnM48yfGUldqGD0S4FFb&t=476) that the guy use the minimap within the VS (not VS Code).

Should I use an extension or how can I get the minimap with my VS?
Thanks!

Comment: Tools > Options > Text Editor > (Language) > Scrollbars > Use map mode

Comment: Does this answer (the inverse of) your question? [How to remove vertical Minimap in visual studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63437873/how-to-remove-vertical-minimap-in-visual-studio)

Comment: Yes, thank you! I could enable the minimap by following the inverse of that question, but your first comment is the same.. that's the option what I need! Thanks again!